# Extending `.eslintrc.base.js`, but omit one plugin from parent

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc

I have an `.eslintrc.base.js` with the following configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
    env: {
        browser: true,
        node: true,
        jest: true
    },
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:react/recommended',
        'prettier'
    ],
    // ...
}
```

Most sub-packages in my project inherit this and just add to the rules or modify a couple of rules.

For one package though, I'd like to omit `plugin:react/recommended`, which the base config extends.

Is this possible? Or do I need to create an additional layer of config files, something like this:

- `.eslintrc.base.js`: as it is now, but without `plugin:react/recommended`
- `.eslintrc.base.react.js`: extends base config, adding react elements
- `<package>/.eslintrc.js`: extends either `.eslintrc.base` or `.eslintrc.base.react`

Comment: You will need to do this .eslintrc.base.js: as it is now, but without plugin:react/recommended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a single ESLint configuration file and specify `overrides` in it.

```json
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "prettier"
  ],
  //override "extends" for the package for which you want to omit "plugin:react/recommended"
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["package/that/omits/plugin/react/*"],
      "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "prettier"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Oh, nice. Thanks! I did end up going the multiple config file route at the time, but this is much nicer & exactly what I was looking for.